# Total variation distance for product measures

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples, total-variation

Consider two measurable spaces $X$ and $Y$ and form their Cartesian product $X\times Y$, with the product $\sigma$-algebra.

> In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4240767/total-variation-distance-on-product-space) I asked whether, given probability measures $p$
> and $q$ on $X\times Y$, their [total variation distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_variation_distance_of_probability_measures)
> $$ d(p,q) = \sup_{f:X\times Y\to[0,1]} \left| \int f \, dp - \int f\, dq \right| $$
> can be equivalently be tested using products of functions, i.e.
> whether
> $$ d(p,q) = \sup_{g:X\to[0,1],\, h:Y\to[0,1]} \left| \int gh \, dp - \int gh\, dq \right| . $$

The answer, in general, is negative.

However, what can we say if $p$ and $q$ are product measures, that is, if there are measures $m$ and $n$ on $X$ and $m',n'$ on $Y$ such that $p=m\otimes m'$ and $q=n\otimes n'$? Can we still find a counterexample in that case?

Comment: For people who are used to the definition of total variation distance in terms of measurable sets, see this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3287889/show-that-the-total-variation-distance-of-probability-measures-mu-nu-is-equa?rq=1